# Firebase FCM Topic - Can it be a user ID that users are subscribed to?

Tags: ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Firebase. As per their documentation, we can send mass notifications to devices subscribed to certain 'Topic' - can these topic be dynamic? Can the topic be a user ID - let's say a contributor's ID so that messages can be sent to devices subscribed to that particular contributor?

For instance: as per the documented example:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "condition": "'dogs' in topics",
  "priority" : "high",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    "title" : "FCM Message",
  }
}
```

---

Can we have 
"condition" : "'contributor_id' in topics",

Or is there any other way to go about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The topic can be any string value, so yes it can be dynamic. You can see the function definition [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToTopic) (Node.js Admin SDK) which defines `topic` as a `string` type.

You can define any extra properties on the message payload as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#defining_the_message_payload):

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: "FCM Message",
    body: "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!"
  },
  data: {
    condition: contributor_id
  }
}
```

Comment: the created Topic seems to take several hours (day ?) toappear in console. When I subsrcibe to a dynamic topic  I don't receive anything

Comment: From my experience, it can take up to 24hrs for a topic to be created. I can't find official documentation about it, but this is from *my* past experience.